# MariaDB/SQL Query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to build a personal website that has a "This Day In History".

**I want to query:**

database name: history

Table: this_day

Column: date

I am able to find queries that will show me items that are "Today's Date".

However, I am trying to get items that happened on this day in "History" by only showing results with the current month and day, minus the year.

Any help would be great :)

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please provide the query you used. Maybe also provide the result of the following query: 'DESCRIBE this_day date;'.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
select * from this_day where MONTH(date) = 1 and DAY(date) = 9
```

Comment: In order to get results tomorrow, I would have to change the 9 to a 10? I would like to have the system find out by it self what the current date is and take that information to see what happened on this day and month. Sorry, I did not explain that part.

Comment: You can try  `select DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)); `

Comment: When I run that query the result that I get is: "10"

Comment: Yes i posted the command in order to help you to find tomorrow date.

Comment: awe, okay. Thank you for your help! I am trying to have the computer to determine the current date, take that information to find other entries with the current month and day, minus the year.